# Missing dhcp package after yocto build on raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, wifi, yocto

I recently created a custom minimal image for Raspberry Pi 4 board using the Yocto build tool, my goal is to control the board with ssh protocol with my desktop, to do so i tried connecting it to wifi. I configured wpa_supplicant.conf and managed to connect my raspberry to the network but with no internet access. After the *wpa_supplicant -B -Dnl80211 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0*

I do get :

```
wlan0 : Associated with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
wlan0: WPA: Key negociation completed with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX completed [id=0 id_str=]
```

Then I realized that dhcpd commands weren't working and the library wasn't available on my image.
How can I add this library on my image, can I install it directly on my micro SD or must I build a new image? My bblayers.conf looks like this

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/ryan/poky/meta \
  /home/ryan/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/ryan/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/ryan/poky/meta-raspberrypi \
  /home/ryan/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/ryan/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /home/ryan/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  /home/ryan/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  /home/ryan/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems \"
```

And inside meta there is : recipes-connectivity which has a dhcpcd file, should have it been added during the build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `dhcpcd` recipe in:

```
meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-connectivity/dhcpcd
```

which contains the description for what you need:

```
SECTION = "console/network"
SUMMARY = "dhcpcd - a DHCP client"
DESCRIPTION = "dhcpcd runs on your machine and silently configures your computer to work on the attached networks without trouble and mostly without configuration."
```

So, just add it to your image:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " dhcpcd"
```

There is `dhcp` recipe also in poky if you want the full server/client package

```
poky/meta/recipes-connectivity/dhcp/
```

Also, `busybox` has it own DHCP client `udhcpc`.

I assume that `busybox` is integrated into your build, so check for `udhcpc` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was going to reinstall and build again for no reason. wpa_cli status gave me "wpa_state=COMPLETED" line so I was guessing I was connected but still had no internet, all I had left to do was to : udhcp -i wlan.